# How do I get Instafeed to show up on all tabs of my webpage?

Tags: html, instagram, shopify

I'm using Shopify to create my webpage. Instafeed for some reason only renders on the "Home" page. On all of the other tabs, about us, shop, blog, the text "Instagram Feed" appears as it should, but the feed is not there. Anyone able to provide any assistance?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide/have a closer look at your theme files.

Usually front page is pulled from template templates/index.liquid and the others from templates/page.liquid or something like that.

To get the title to display is fairly straight forward. However your theme needs to load the appropriate .js file/s for the feed to populate.

It would be random guessing as to what your code is loading cause you haven't provided ANY code or theme details.

If you can get your theme to load your instagram files through layout/theme.liquid for example, you will have a better chance of seeing it sitewide as the file sits a level hihger that the particular templates/[whateverpage].liquid page type files.

Hope that give you a place to start looking.

Comment: It is on my theme.liquid. The main code source of my website. I'm not sure if I'm wording this is the right manner, I do not know a lot about code. Would you be able to provide any more in depth answers if I upload a screenshot of the code?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/instafeed.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userFeed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: *******,
        accessToken: '************************************',
        resolution: 'thumbnail',
        limit: '8'
      
    });
    userFeed.run();
</script>

Comment: It will work on the theme liquid, or home page, but doesn't populate to the other pages. Just to clarify.

Comment: It could be as simple as the src url for that script load. Your template should reference your asset_url and look something like 
`{{ 'script.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}`

That will ensure that it is loaded correctly regardless of your url hierarchy.


In other words the snippet in your comment may load for foo.com, but will not find the file in foo.com/pages/bar, because the path will be incorrect then.


If you use the template method to inject scripts, they will look after the path for you.

Again, you did not supply your theme code or details, so we're just guessing at the moment.